# Slow read performance in Mac OS X terminal, with external encryption enabled hard drive

Tags: terminal, encryption, git, hdd

Anyone experienced really slow performance with Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) file systems? I have git LFS project on my hard drive and for some reason even as simple as `cd project-folder` takes minutes to run (or `ls -l` command). Any other folder is performing well. It seems there is some kind of issue with combining ecryption, git LFS and external HDD?

Tried searching web, but only finding slowness to download the git LFS files. I don't have issues with that, but only when using basic commands in project folder.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not usual to experience "really slow performance" on MacOS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) file systems (also known as HFS+ encrypted). That configuration is extremely widely used, so any intrinsic problems here would have been reported in huge numbers.

I have been using Git-LFS on such a file system for a very long time, and never experience any such slowness. I know that many of my fellow developers do not have the problem either.

I.e. this is not a general problem for everyone, but instead seems to be a local problem with your computer.

I would use regular file system diagnostics to check your file system. Use Disk Utility or fsck on the command line. Also checks your system logs to see if the OS reports any I/O errors or timeouts during these slow performing commands.

As you mentioned it is external harddrive, you might also have an interface problem with your cabling or similar. I would try creating new large files (unrelated files) and see if they are also slow.

Also check the number of files inside the directory you're cd'ing into to see if it is a very large number - that could also potentially be a cause.

Comment: thanks for your input @jksoegaard you were right, that this was related to my configurations. It was terminal prompt (liquidprompt) that I was using, it caused git status run that made it really slow. Previously git LFS project was on my local SSD drive and that was running smoothly. Conclusion: HDDs are really slow...